# How to run a script on login that can capture camera output

Tags: macos, login-items, daemons

I have the following shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
time=$(time);
imagesnap -q "/var/captures/$time.jpg";
```

When I run it in the terminal, everything works. But when I run it using `launchtl` or `crontab` at login, nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to run this script at login? It it even possible?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

### Note

The issue is not with `crontab` or `launchctl`, I have got them to work. They just wont work with the camera.

I am using [Imagesnap](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/imagesnap#default) as a dependency for capturing images.

### My Machine

I am using macOS 14.1 Beta 2 on a 2021 macBook Pro

Comment: Does [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464039/how-to-register-some-program-at-login-for-all-users-on-macos) help?

Comment: Is the command running as root or under your account? Is it possible to set a delay before calling imagesnap, maybe the camera isn't set up yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Automator application to create a application to run the script, as shown below.

[image]

You could then add this application to the items that will open automatically when you log in.